# Calculate total through datasheet and subdatasheet in MS Access

Tags: t-sql, ms-access

I have an table (OutgoingInvoice) with each invoice total. The other table Products contains all the purchased product linked to the OutgoingInvoice table (where we sold):
[image]

- How can I calculate and display the profit? (OutgoingInvoice.SUMSUM minus All linked Product's SUM)
- Is it possible to hide some Subdatasheet columns?

Edit:
- I can't use Dsum cross tables (expression builder do not allow it)
- So I decided to use query with Subdatasheet. Its working except 1 thing: The Subdatasheet not filtered (to show only a proper InvoiceID-OutgoingInvoice)
[image]

How can  I do it?

Comment: Cannot do that calc in table. Build a report. Yes, can hide columns with right click menu.

Comment: Can do that profit calc in query using aggregate query joined to invoices table or DSum() or use form/subform arrangement.

Comment: Unabla to use DSUM() from another table. But SubDatashett look ok, but How can I filter to IDs? (See edited question)

Comment: If relationships are properly set up, subatasheet should only show records related to parent record on main sheet. This is a design issue, not programming, and therefore not really appropriate for SO.